# Can the proteins in Whey protein contribute to nasal allergies?

Tags: protein-shakes

I think I've worked out when my allergies got a lot worse.. its when I started going to the gym which was also when I started taking whey protein. Has anyone experienced a correlation and or know of scientific evidence supporting such a hypothesis?

Comment: Do you have any evidence that would indicate this is even a risk? Instead of it just being hay fever or something like that, which is you know, much more likely?

Comment: Many food allergies manifest themselves as the symptoms of hay fever so I'm hoping thats it. I'll post my results once I'm a few weeks into making the switch. My hay fever at the moment is terrible and anti-histamines do nothing.

Comment: If anyone is interested, I did a hardcore liver cleanse and my allergy symptoms have improved a thousand %!! If anyone is interested hit me up and I'll tell you what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whey comes from milk.  It's part of the byproducts of processing milk and is one of the components made into cheese.  The reason I point this out is that some people are allergic to milk.  While the whey protein powder processing *usually* removes the disagreeable parts for those who are lactose intolerant, it is still whey.

If dairy in general (cheese, milk, etc.) causes nasal allergies, then there is no reason why whey protein which comes from milk will not cause the same thing.

In short, it comes down to your own allergies.  If you have no allergies, then you can expect no detrimental affects.  If you do have allergies, then you can expect those allergies to behave the same way they always do.

Comment: Thank you for the intelligent and thoughtful answer. People with a cursory understanding of dairy allergies usually immediately confuse it with lactose intolerance (which is caused by a gene (correctly) switching off after we are weened from breast milk). As I understand it, most allergies are your bodies (incorrect) immune response to proteins. People can be mildly allergic to milk (often without knowing it). As vegetable proteins are unpalatable I might try whey protein derived from a2 milk (eliminates a1 beta-casein which many milk allergies originate from).